# Why kernel modesetting, instead of privilege separation?

Tags: kernel, xorg, drivers

Kernel modesetting was kind of painful to get on Linux at first, but now it's pretty awesome to have. I mean, X not need to run as root? High-res hardware accelerated consoles? Cool stuff.

Problem is, a lot of UNIX platforms don't have modesetting kernel drivers of any sort. So hardware that relies on KMS is now mostly limited to Linux.

My question: why actually implement this in the kernel?

If hardware access is needed to set the screen resolution, why not use a separate privileged daemon, or a small setuid binary? That would maintain the advantage of separating out the privileged code, and letting the display server run as limited user; while getting rid of the special driver requirement, and making cross-UNIX support easier. Right? Or am I missing something significant here?

Comment: That's the idea behind [microkernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) OS architectures.

Comment: In this case I'm not thinking microkernel type model, more just portability between disparate kernels.

Comment: KMS is also being used by OpenBSD and FreeBSD, and Solaris has also KMS in the works. This way when developers make a working driver for Linux then the driver support will also flow to others that use KMS.

Comment: It's an architectural thing. Hardware access is one, if not THE, task of a kernel. Splitting the work between kernel and userspace is awkward, because you will need two components that actually do only one piece of work  with a blurry interface. Ultimately you will perform work within the kernel's domain, therefore there is a strong case for putting the whole thing in the kernel. Of course you can implement it however and whereever you want. Robust platforms are all about clearly(!) defined architectures and interfaces. It's all wibbly wobbly.

Comment: There was quite a long period in which various kinds of crashes would leave the console in a weird mode where X wasn't working any more, but TTY-style conole access was not actually restored.   IIRC GL acceleration problems and crashes used to provoke this situation quite often.  KMS means that the kernel knows how to fix the problem and restore the state of the console.  IOW partly a usability improvement.  While one might argue that the kernel could ask a userspace daemon to do this, I guess that might not always work well.  Also putting it in the kernel means no closed-source difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel already manages network hardware, audio hardware, fans and other hardware, so it makes sense that graphics hardware is also managed by the kernel.